# Login Panel Validation Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to make a basic login panel in MVC. I have a MemberLogin class as a model, and a MemberController. I tried to add a view with name "Login", template "Empty", model class "MemberLogin (LoginPanel.Models)" and data contex class "ApplicationDbContext (LoginPanel.Models)" and received a validation error as below:

> There was an error running the selected code generator. Unabled to retrieve metadata for 'LoginPanel.Models.LoginViewModel'. One or more validation errors were dedected during model generation.
>
> LoginViewModel:EntityType 'LoginViewModel' has no keydefined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>
> LoginViewModels:EntityType: EntitySet 'LoginViewModels' is based on type 'LoginViewModel' that has no keys defined.

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

```
namespace LoginPanel.Models
{
    public class MemberLogin
    {
        
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}


using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace LoginPanel.Controllers
{
    public class MemberController : Controller
    {
      public ActionResult Giris()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

How I can overcome this problem?

Comment: Your error relates to `LoginViewModel` but you have not even shown the code relating to it.

Comment: That is the problem already!. I tried to add code automatically and received this error. Then ı solved the problem by writing it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write the "view" myself instead of creating automatically. And it Works.

```
@model LoginPanel.Models.MemberLogin
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<h2>Member Login</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, new { @class="control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.UserName)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.Password)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```